# IRS-4506T, Request for Tax Transcripts reporting delay

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs

sometimes lending institutions ask for a request of tax transcript for the past two years. This is done by filing a IRS-4506T, and then the IRS sends the transcripts to the designated person.

This year is 2014, where 2013 tax returns were filed. Unfortunately, this transcript doesn't include the tax return filed in the current year **until a certain point in time**. I don't know when this is but I would like to know

It isn't a one year delay, for instance, the 2013 tax return filed in 2014 won't appear on this transcript after 2014 tax returns are filed in 2015.

But at the same time, I don't know when the current year's tax return starts to appear on requested IRS tax transcripts

At what point in time would my IRS tax transcript begin showing the 2013 tax returns. Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transcript should appear shortly after your tax return was received and accepted by the IRS. You should check on the IRS page, I [wrote about it here](http://littleadvisor.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/great-new-service-from-the-irs-get-your-account-transcripts-online/).

Comment: Yes thats relevant, the answer is August 1st

Comment: @littleadv edited the answer to include a link to the [IRS page itself](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Get-Transcript) so people don't have to go through a blog post on another site to get it.

Comment: @littleadv Why? Shouldn't an answer at least contain a direct link to the site it's talking about? The information should be *here* not on a blog post somewhere else. Why not put the explanation here and then link to your blog instead of just advertising your own blog without including any helpful info here? This just comes across as spam without any info.

Comment: @MA - the relevant point is whether the answer, here, the first line, is sufficient. When I read it and quit, it passes for an answer. The link is 'further reading." That's the criteria. His choice to not accept your link addition.